# How can I create exe file of a flutter desktop application project which contains a sqlite database?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, flutter-test, flutter-desktop

## I am trying to create a exe file of my flutter desktop project by using flutter build windows. So the exe file is generated but without the sqlite database which I included in the project. So I am unable to do CURD operations using the exe application.

I tried importing the .db file inside the application folder but it didnt work.
please help me out so that I can install my appliction with the local database present in it.